# How do i create a 'FeatureFiles' folder within Eclipse > src/test/resources?

Tags: eclipse

How do i create a 'FeatureFiles' folder within Eclipse > src/test/resources?

I can create a folder within src/test/java but how do i created the following folder listed below? 
[image]

thanks

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Package. Packages are equivalent to folders:

Right click `src/test/resources`, hover over the ***New*** tab and click ***Package***. You will be prompted with a window containing a textfield in which you will enter the package name. If the name textfield is empty, then name the package "**FeatureFiles**"; if the name textfield is occupied, then add "**.FeatureFiles**" at the end.

If you want your **resources** folder to be separate as shown in your second image, then create it as a new **`Source Folder`**.

Also, it looks like are using an old version of Eclipse, consider upgrading to a newer version: https://www.eclipse.org/neon/

[image: New Tab]
[image: New Package]

Comment: thanks for the comment how do i create another branch of src/test/resources?

Comment: @Gbru (It's an answer, not a comment :P)  I don't understand what you mean by "create another branch"...

Comment: sorry jact :p, please look at the new image i have attached may make more sense

Comment: @Gbru I still don't understand... Are you trying to make two different folders with the same name?

Comment: please see if the new image i have at attached makes sense?

Comment: @Gbru Ohh! Lemme see. I'll update my answer when I solve that :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142097/discussion-between-jack-kirby-and-gbru).